# Why is my .draggable method returning an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a custom scrollbar and my javascript that is supposed to make the scrollbar draggable won't work. (I am using Chrome to test it)

Why is this returning an error?

```
// JavaScript Document
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#scrollbar-piece").draggable({axis: "y"});
        Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    })
```

Here is the html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="theScriptThatHasAProblem.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-container">...</div>
    <div id="scrollbar">
        <div id="scrollbar-piece"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you missing a script include? jqueryUI perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only including the base jQuery library

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to use `jQuery draggable & droppable` include also

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Edit: Also make sure the scripts are in the correct order. jQuery has to be loaded before jQuery UI, because it depends on it.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8YEyc/

Comment: Are you loading jQuery before jQuery UI?

Answer (score 2):

draggable is part of the jQuery UI library that you do not have referenced.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

[Google CDN information](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui)

[draggable documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Comment: @AnOriginalAlias I updated my answer to show the CDN reference and link to the documenation on draggable

Answer (score 1):

You are missing jQuery UI library.[`draggable`](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) is a component of jquery-ui this not not a part of jQuery.
 You can download stable version from https://jqueryui.com/. Or, you can directly include that from google API as follows:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```